# APQ8064 alsa recording

Tags: android, alsa, nexus-4, tinyalsa

I have a Nexus 4 device (msm8960 with APQ8064 sound card).
I'm trying to record audio from the primary device (pcmC0P0c) using tinyalsa tinycap utility but I encounter the following issues:

- If I do not modify any mixer control, I get an "Unable to open PCM
  device - device not found error"
- When I set one of Multimedia1
  switches to on (e.g. MultiMedia1 Mixer SLIM_4_TX) I get an error
  saying setting hw params failed.

So, my question is: how do I know which controls to set to On (and / or what to set other controls) in order to capture audio successfully?

**Edit:**
After some digging I found that the in `pcm_open` setting pcm params fails in the following call:

```
 if (ioctl(pcm->fd, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HW_PARAMS, &params)) {
    oops(pcm, errno, "cannot set hw params");
    goto fail_close;
}
```

How can I set params correctly so that `pcm_open` will succeed? I couldn't see any issue with the parameters (which BTW work on other devices)

**Edit 2:**
I see the issue is with period size and period count - I can't set to above 150 and 2 respectively. When I change them `pcm_open` succeeds but `pcm_read` fails with "start error" message

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: This depends not only on the specific chips used, but also on how they are wired together. Anyway, the hw_params might indicate that you're just using a wrong sample format.

Comment: I'm using 16 bit sample format and I tried all sampling rates. I also tried single channel and 2 channels - no luck

Comment: See the output of `aplay --dump-hw-params`.

Comment: I'm using tinyalsa and AFAIK there is no option to dump hardware parameters..

Comment: I found out that setting access to SNDRV_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED fails. Question edited with full details

Comment: So it works if you omit that `set_mask` call?

Comment: I re-edited, I think the issue is with set params in general (the set access was just the last one before applying the hw params)

Comment: This means that some parameter is not supported by the hardware.

Comment: I found that it is related to period size and period count (details in re-edited question). when I mange to set them I get a start error message